# Creating a range sliding bar with fixed ranges

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I am attempting to create a range sliding bar. The format I am trying to create this in is to let a user choose their budget, but I want to do so in an easy way. I am using the ui Jquery example as a reference, but with this you can slide the range bars wherever you want. I found an example I like and that is how I am trying to model this:

http://isadoradesign.com/web-design-company-discuss

You will see the slider after the blocks on the right side.

Ultimately, I want the ability to choose certain points on the slider to set the budget. I don't want the user to drag the sliding bar.

So far, what I have done is this:

```
$(function() {
 $( "#slider" ).slider({
  range: true,
  value:100,
  min: 0,
  max: 50000,
  step: 500,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
  }
});
$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
});


<div id="slider"></div>
<p>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
```

I am using the jQuery css smoothness link to create the slider, but would anyone recommend another way I can design the slider myself instead of using jQuery's plugin css?

In the comments below I will attach a JSfiddle with my work so far (I don't know how to upload external sources to a snippet).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=1Dum5RdD5I